# How to inline load txt file into spreadsheet php

Tags: php, csv

So this is the front end of my code.

```
     <li>Inline load into spreadsheet  <a href="redirect.php?
     dl=logfile.txt">logfile.csv</a></li>
```

How would I go about creating a csv file with my logfile.txt that has data in csv format already. 
So far my headers look like this:

```
    header('content-type: text/csv');
    header('Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$value");
    readfile($value);
```

Comment: Start with `$value = $_GET['dl'];` and looks to me like the rest should work.  Have you tried it?  If you did, what happened?

Comment: Here's what I did but it stills force downloads logfile.txt not csv:                                                                            
       $value = $_GET['dl']                                                                
       if($value == "logfile.txt"){
 
 

 header('content-type: text/csv');
 header('Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
 header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$value");
 readfile($value);}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want that, after clicking the link, the user gets a pop-up that allows saving the .csv file and that the file name should already be set to "logfile.csv".  Instead, you are getting the file in the browser and/or with file name "logfile.txt".  If this is not the case, update your post with specifics.

First, I would change `Content-Disposition` from `inline` (tells the browser to display the file as a web page) to `attachment` (tells the browser to save the file locally; see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)).  Next, the value of `filename` in `Content-Disposition` should be set to the file name with .csv, not with .txt as you are doing in your code.

Here are the additional/changed lines of code ...

```
$value_csv = substr($value, 0, strrpos($filename, ".")) . '.csv';
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$value_csv");
```